# can anyone help me to do laravel notification process from each models.For example: i have two models one is passport and other is voterid.?

Tags: laravel

can anyone help me to do laravel notification process from each models.For example: i have two models one is passport and other is voterid.Each model contains a field expiry date.I want the user to get notification on the expiry dates of each model in a notification bell icon?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question should include more details and clarify the problem. What have you done so far?

Comment: i have created crud pages for passport and voterid in laravel already

Comment: i want to get the user notified that his passport is going to expire on the day before his passport expirydate.I have created a field expiry date in passport table of my laravel project

Answer (score 0):

Even though the comment above is correct, I want to give you some more hints and tips. In general Laravel has a pretty good documentation. I will show you where you can get all of your info.

First take a look at the Task Scheduler, Commands and Notifications.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/scheduling 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#writing-commands 
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications

I would create a custom command that gets all entries of your models that are expired. To alert the user I would send a Notification for every expired Model.
This command can then be scheduled to run say every hour by the scheduler.
For that you will also need to setup a CRON job, you will set this up for your system (and not in your laravel app), the cron job calls the `php artisan scheduler:run` command which checks if your app has to run your custom command.

If you are using Ubuntu this might help you out in setting up cron jobs:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-setup-cron-jobs-in-ubuntu/

If you have many models I would recommend using Queues to send the notifications. This might help improve performance issues if you have large databases.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications#queueing-notifications